# How to create two sets of radio buttons in one line in an html table

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table in an angular app where I have 4 radio buttons in one line however I would like to separate them into two groups of two radio buttons, so that a user can choose an option yes/ no in painful section and yes/no in non-painful section. How could I do that? My code is below:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>

            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th colspan="2">Non Painful</th>
            <th colspan="2">Painful</th>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>No</td>
                <td>Yes</td>

                <td>No</td>
                <td>Yes</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1.1</td>
                <td>Moaning</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q1" id="q1.1-no" value="No" [(ngModel)]="survey.moaningNonPainful">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q1" id="q1.1-yes" value="Yes" [(ngModel)]="survey.moaningNonPainful">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q1" id="q1.2-No" value="No" [(ngModel)]="survey.moaningPainful">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q1" id="q1.2-Yes" value="Yes" [(ngModel)]="survey.moaningPainful">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Radio buttons are grouped by sharing the same `name=""` attribute value.

Comment: Does it have to be in a table?  Perhaps the ``<fieldset>`` and ``<legend>`` tags might be helpful.

Comment: I know about this approach but this time it had to be a table, Dai's answer solved my problem, not sure how I could have missed that. Thanks for help :)